# SQL count from multiple databases and insert with database name

Tags: sql, multiple-tables

Trying to count from multiple databases (which I'm able to do), but I'd like to have the count results in a table near the database name.

My end result would be:

| DbName | unarchived_measurements |
| --- | --- |
| hdb1 | 10 |
| hdb2 | 14 |
| hdb3 | 9 |

Code:

```
DECLARE @DT datetime = DATEADD(hour, -3, GETUTCDATE())
DECLARE @DbName VARCHAR(64)
DECLARE @unarchived_measurements_count TABLE (DbName VARCHAR(64), unarchived_measurements INT)

INSERT INTO @unarchived_measurements_count (DbName) 
    SELECT name 
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE name LIKE 'H%'

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT DbName FROM @unarchived_measurements_count

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DbName  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    EXEC (
        'select count(*) as unarchived_measurements' 
        + ' FROM ' + @DbName + '.dbo.measurements' 
        + ' WHERE date < DATEADD(hour, -3, GETUTCDATE()) and processing_stage = 200'
        )

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DbName 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor 

SELECT * FROM @unarchived_measurements_count
```

I tried with insert statement, but this just add new rows. I tried to update but kept getting errors.

Thanks

Comment: What errors, specifically?

Comment: @Kurt - I guess the errors don't matter here. The above code is running but obviously does not do what I need.
My other attempts with insert or update resulted in errors, but it's probably not the right way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simpler than I thought it would be (not my original desire but good enough):

```
EXEC (
    'select count(*) as archived_measurements_' **+ @DbName**
    + ' FROM ' + @DbName + '.dbo.measurements' 
    + ' WHERE date > DATEADD(hour, -5, GETUTCDATE())'
    )
```